# where + past participle?

Tags: grammar

1-) And the plastic bodices, **where shown**, were more than welcome.

2-) The nanospherical formed **where shown** to have high surface area.

3-) If popular photo-sharing apps like Instagram are like Facebook, **where closed** networks of
friends share images, Color is more like Twitter, in that it is far more public.

Is where+past participle in these sentences is a reduced adverbial or not or what ? How should we think ? I couldn't understand ? Thank you.

Comment: #2 looks like an error.  I think it should really be "**were** shown".  (Probably also *nanospheres*, not *nanospherical*.) Did you find these sentences somewhere?  Links would help.

Comment: (3) says that, in Facebook, closed networks of friends share images, and Instagram is like that too. The meaning of (1) is not clear without more context, but presumably it means _in cases where they were shown_.